# What is the optimal way to display a multiple choice list?

Tags: lists, checkboxes, readability, choices

I'm looking for suggestions for displaying multiple choice lists.

[image: vertical text]

My first (and naive) solution. Obviously, 90° vertical text is unnecessarily hard to read and takes up a lot of vertical screen real estate.

[image: slanted text]

Slanted text works better. Takes up less vertical space and is easier to read.

[image: slanted text with lines]

Adding lines might increase usability, although IMO it's less aesthetically pleasing.

[image: different direction]

This solution is quite different from the others, but might work well for a limited number of choices. One thing I don't really like is that this layout seems to communicate that it's almost mandatory to select at least one option, which is not the case.

---

#### The question

Are there alternative solutions that, for example, provide better readability and take up less space?

The choices need to be visible at all time. The horizontal space is limited (around 640px). There could be as much as 15 checkboxes.

I'm not against going in a completely different direction, but I can't think of anything that would be superior.

Answer (score 2):

I find slanted text with added lines really neat and readable solution. What might help is a balloon with hint once you hover over a certain check box - so the user knows a check-box for who they are checking.

See the picture:

[image: Vertical choices]

Of course, the colours of the tooltip should correspond with the page design but on the other hand be visible.